# Secure software license check/validation

Tags: c#, php, mysql, security

I am implementing a licensing system into my software using a MySQL database with the license key and unique machine ID (combination of MAC code, CPU code and others). I was looking for a secure way to check the validity of a license key that the user enters into a text box in a C# application. My current method is to connect to a simple PHP file like http://example.com/checklicense.php?=LICENSEKEYGOESHERE and return a "VALID" (+ the machine ID) or "INVALID" string. Then I would access this file and get the return string from the C# application by using a `WebClient` or `WebRequest`.

Obviously, using this current method is insecure as you could redirect the URL to the localhost and fake the result. I guess my real question is, using this method, how can I make it more secure? Is there a way for my C# application to identify that it is connecting to the real PHP file by signing it or something?

Answer (score 2):

Your license server must give an important information to the software, not that simple "valid/invalid" flag, if you want to make sure that it should not be easily faked. Additionally, the answer of the server should change over time in a non-predictable way, otherwise it is barely better than the previous flag solution.

Note that on the other side, you must make your customers aware that their software will stop working if your server goes down. I bet you'll get some angry calls and threats of lawsuits if you didn't tell them, and things break in the middle of **your** night... Be prepared to guarantee 100% uptime of your license server 24/7.